# Bootstrap3: Dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a site using Bootstrap 3.0.0
All is fine except that the dropdown menu is not working.
In the head of the file i am making this declarations:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

Something is missing there?

The html should be correct:

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown-example<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#link-1">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link-2">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link-3">link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#link-4">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Does anyone knows how to do?

Comment: Could you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ of this? It will help solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Link to your external javascript file `jquery.js` before `Bootstrap.js`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

You need to load jQuery *before* you use it.

Comment: Now when i click it appears a yellow rectangle around the box, before no. But still does not show the dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this scripts should be probably included at the end of html document

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

Did you include jQuery too? Bootstrap plugins depend on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I added jquery.js but unfortunately is still not working

Comment: i believe that it's because of the library import order... Could you post the whole code using pastebin or http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Ok, thank you.
The css i have taken from bootstraptor, and is a showcase of many possibilities of Bootstrap 3.
All it works fine except dropdown.
Also for another project i need dropdown and is not working.
I am not understanding what i miss to make it working...

Here i put the code:

http://paste.laravel.com/OmT

Answer (score 0):

Just close the tag where you link to bootstrap.css. The "/" before the last angle bracket is missing in the code in your question. `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`